# Source of entropy for PoW hash

Tags: hash, proof-of-work

How does bitcoin do it to generate an (upredictable) hash in each new block with sufficient randomness so that no one can precompute it?

Answer (score 2):

Each block contains the hash of the previous, which is unpredictable. Also, the transactions in each block themselves are unpredictable because one can't tell who is paying who and how much.